# Dificultad dento de un If y un For dentro del codigo

Tags: python-3.x

Dentro del codigo tengo 2 dificultades:

1. Dentro de la función `agregar_horario()`, debo arreglar el hecho de que si hay una materia "A" que tiene las horas [8,9] y otra materia "B" que toma las materias [7,8]
   No se podria agregar la materia "B". Dado que una de las horas ya esta ocupada por una materia. ¿Como podria solucionar esto?
2. Dentro de la función `crear_horario()` ocurre una cosa y es que, hay ocasiones en las que si se crean horarios con la cantidad de materias que se indica en el codigo, como hay ocasiones en las que me crea un horario con una cantidad menor. **Cuando dentro de los horarios siempre esta la posibilidad de crear un horario con las 4 materias solicitadas.** ¿Porque ocurre esta situacion?

```py
import random 

# l:0, m:1, w:2, j:3, v:4, s:5, d:6

#BASE DE DATOS: Referencia a las asignaturas que quiere cursar y los horarios disponibles

        # Nombre materia, grupo, {horario}
        # Horario: key = dia, value = [hora del dia]      
materia = ['Ecuaciones', 12, {1:[10,11],3:[10,11]}]
materia_12 = ['Ecuaciones', 1, {1:[6,7],3:[6,7]}]
materia_1 = ['Ecuaciones', 3, {1:[8,9],3:[8,9]}]
materia_2 = ['Ecuaciones', 4, {1:[10,11],3:[10,11]}]
materia_3 = ['Varias', 13, {1:[8,9],3:[8,9]}]
materia_4 = ['Varias', 3, {1:[10,11],3:[10,11]}]
materia_5 = ['Varias', 4, {1:[10,11],3:[10,11]}]
materia_6 = ['Varias', 5, {1:[8,9],3:[8,9]}]
materia_7 = ['Varias', 8, {1:[12,13],3:[12,13]}]
materia_8 = ['Varias', 9, {1:[12,13],3:[12,13]}]
materia_9 = ['Análisis', 1, {1:[16,17],3:[16,17]}]
materia_10 = ['Anillos', 1, {1:[8,9],3:[8,9]}]
materia_11 = ['Probabilidad', 1, {1:[8,9],3:[8,9]}]
horarios = [ materia, materia_1, materia_2, materia_3, materia_4, materia_5, materia_6, materia_7, materia_8, materia_9, materia_10, materia_11, materia_12]



def agregar_horario(semana, grupos, nombre_materia, grupo, horario):
    #Me divida {horario} en sus dias             
    day_1, day_2= horario.items()

    # Si el nombre de la materia ya dentro de grupos  
    # Si el [hora_1 , hora_2] no esta dentro de los valores de la semana en ese dia
    # Entonces agregar esa materia tanto a semana, como a grupos


    '''
    Aqui hay que arreglar el hecho de que si hay una materia "A" que tiene las horas [8,9] y otra materia "B" que toma las materias [7,8]
    No se podria agregar la materia "B"
    '''

    if  nombre_materia not in grupos.keys() and day_1[1] not in semana[day_1[0]].values() and day_2[1] not in semana[day_2[0]].values():
      semana[day_1[0]][nombre_materia] = day_1[1]
      semana[day_2[0]][nombre_materia] = day_2[1]
      grupos[nombre_materia] = grupo
    
    return [semana, grupos]

def crear_horario(horarios, cant_materias):
    #Cada vez que se crea un horario tanto semana, como grupos esta vacio
    semana = [{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
    grupos = {}

    #Con cada horario dentro de horarios
    for i in horarios:
        resultado = agregar_horario(semana, grupos, i[0], i[1], i[2])
        semana = resultado[0]
        grupos = resultado[1]

        #Agregar un horario a Semana y a grupos, hasta que la Cantidad de materias sea igual a las materias agregadas
        if len(grupos) == cant_materias:
            break
    '''
    Aqui el parecer hay ocasiones en las que retorna horarios con una cantidad menor a la de Cantidad de Materias
    '''
    return [grupos, semana]


def main(horarios, cant_materias):
    pregunta = input('Di NO cuando no quieras ver mas horarios diferentes: ')
    #Para no consumir procesador de computo calculando todos los horarios posibles, simplemente pregunto si desea un nuevo horario o no
    while pregunta != "NO":
    #Evitando que se creen los mismos horarios con {random.shuffle} se mueve aleatoriamente el orden dentro de horarios
      random.shuffle(horarios)
      print(crear_horario(horarios, cant_materias))
      pregunta = input('')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(horarios, 4)
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Aun no he dado con la solución del segundo, tienen alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

Arregle el primer error de esta forma:

```
def agregar_horario(semana, grupos, nombre_materia, grupo, horario):           
    day_1, day_2= horario.items()

    if  nombre_materia not in grupos.keys() and day_1[1] not in semana[day_1[0]].values() and day_2[1] not in semana[day_2[0]].values() and [i+1 for i in day_1[1]]not in semana[day_1[0]].values() and [i+1 for i in day_2[1]] not in semana[day_2[0]].values() and [i-1 for i in day_1[1]]not in semana[day_1[0]].values() and [i-1 for i in day_2[1]] not in semana[day_2[0]].values():
      semana[day_1[0]][nombre_materia] = day_1[1]
      semana[day_2[0]][nombre_materia] = day_2[1]
      grupos[nombre_materia] = grupo
    
    return [semana, grupos]
```

lo que hice es que tambien comparara tanto el horario que me dan como agregandole una hora y quitandole una hora, de esta forma aunque no sea el mismo horario no se tomara dado que esa hora ya esta ocupada por otra materia.